# Select distinct value from one column, using another for ordering

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with two columns, Name (nvarchar(256)) and Score (int between 0 and 100). Each name can have more than one score. I know it should be simple, but I can't work out how to get one table containing each name only once, and the top score for that name. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is `Name` actually a `text` datatype?, if so, please stop using it, is deprecated already. You won't be able to use it on a `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, and many, many more restrictions

Comment: it's actually nvarchar (just checked) Updating the op

Comment: What if you have two people named James? How are you going to tell which is which? Are you sure name is the column you want to group by?

Comment: It's better to define a primary key and then do group by...

Comment: In this case, name is a uniquely assigned character string (Name is probably not the right title for that column but I'm not in charge of that), The answers given work, I knew I was missing something obvious, I just can't accept any of them yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would be:

```
select [Name], max([Score])
from t1
group by [Name]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
SELECT Name, max(score)
  FROM Table
  GROUP BY Name
```

should do what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT Name, MAX(Score)
FROM t
GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Name, max(Score) as Score
FROM table
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Score desc
```

I suggest you to give a look at [W3Schools SQL Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp). It explains the basic things and the basic functions (on the right SQL Basic and SQL Functions), if you give a look at these lessons you'll be able to do lot of things by yourself, it takes about 20 minutes of reading + the time you should reserve for trying ;)

Comment: [Just say no to W3Schools](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120025/will-i-be-downvoted-for-giving-a-w3schools-link).

Comment: I think it is a good starting point for people who miss basics. Sure it's not a reference to use, just a starting point for basics